# Play h264 encoded videos on android device from stream

Tags: android, ios, video, vlc, gpuimage

I'm working on certain project that allows some video editing, uploading edited video to server (Amazon S3) and playing this video on device.

The iOS version is already completed. I'm using there GPUImage to edit and encode videos.
I'm using quicktime container and h264 codec.

Now I'm working on android version of this project and have encountered several problems.

While I'm able to download and play these videos (encoded on iPhone) on the android devices, I'm not able to play the stream of these videos on most of android devices.

I have done some research and one of advices was to add some code to iOS postencoding that converts to mp4 and fixes MooV http://fabiensanglard.net/mobile_progressive_playback/index.php, but it doesn't help.
The only thing that I have achieved after that "fix" is to hear audio track and not getting error message on Galaxy SII device, but on other devices there is the same story.

After that I have downloaded VLC player from play store and it plays these videos.

So my question is, what do I need to do to play h264 stream?

How can I implement my own video player or how can I use VLC source code to play these videos.

Comment: Have you fix this issue please share your views...